# Converting protocol buffers to/from JSON in C, without generating C code

Tags: c, json, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I need to use `.desc` files to enable the reading of serialized protocol-buffer messages and their conversion to JSON (using jansson).

This is because the protocol-buffer message formats will change much more frequently than the C code.  The `.desc` files will be a runtime input to the executable.

I've found https://github.com/Sannis/protobuf2json-c but my reading of this is that it needs C code to be generated.  In particular the `ProtobufCMessage` needs to exist for the message being decoded, and I cannot see a way of making a ProtobufCMessage (from `/usr/include/google/protobuf-c/protobuf-c.h`) without generating C code.

Have I missed something here, or will I need to write new code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `.desc` extension but I'm guessing from the context that it is a file containing a protobuf `FileDescriptorProto`, defined in `google/protobuf/descriptor.proto`.

To do what you want, you will most likely need to use the Protobuf C++ or Java library, each of which defines a class `DynamicMessage` which has the ability to emulate arbitrary message types based on descriptors. You can then combine this with any Protobuf-JSON library that is based on the standard Protobuf reflection interfaces. (You can also write your own JSON converter pretty easily; use the `TextFormat` class (found in both the C++ and Java Protobuf libs) as a template.)

My understanding is that protobuf-c does not currently contain an equivalent to `DynamicMessage`.

Comment: A `.desc` file is the information from `.proto` file(s), encoded in a protocol buffer format described by `descriptor.proto`.